# Keep space / padding between Divs

Tags: html, space, between, justify

How would I be able to keep the space between my inlined div elements without counting the space as 'pixels'?

For example, currently i'm using margin-right (as my padding between my elements) but is eventually counting that as pixels (the result shows off ugly, see JsFiddle, div element gets pushed down).

```
#parent .child
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 16.5%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39r89drf/1/)

Basically, I just like to have the first item floaten left and the last item floaten right. Now I know many of you guys are thinking, why not just use the feature 'justify'? I've tried using it, but it isn't a really good option since the amount of elements can be everything (10, 5, 8, etc).

Help would be appericiated!

EDIT: This basically is the feature i'd like to achieve but for multiple elements (instead of having only 1 row, there could be 2-16 rows.
[image]

Comment: Why not use [flexbox's `justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)?

Comment: I want this working using non-css3 features

Comment: You should [edit] your question to specify that.

Comment: [This fiddle may be the closest you will get without CSS3 features.](http://jsfiddle.net/39r89drf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align: justify`. It won't justify the last line, but you can force a new line with a pseudo-element:

```css
#parent {
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: red;
}
#parent:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
#parent .child {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 16.5%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was on my way :) +1

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, i've tried the same method but then placing a span element at the bottom of the parent's div, and give it the text-align justify effect. But the effect is horrible since there can be any amount of childs.

Comment: @Bilal075 I think my code behaves like your image. If that's not what you want, please clarify how it should behave.

Comment: @Oriol Well basically what I want to achieve is that all the elements are floaten left with a white space (padding) on it's right. The only issue i'm having right now is that whenever the element is close to the right side of the page, the margin is counted aswell, and the div will therefore be pushen down. Basically I just want to have a padding between the div's without the browser counting it.

Comment: @Oriol Something like this JsFiddle, but without placing the elements inside a 'row' http://jsfiddle.net/d5VTg/73/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it properly, you want to set an internal margin between the children, but not between the edge children and the parent. Something like

```css
.child { margin-right: 15px; }
.child:last-of-line { margin-right: 0; }
```

Currently there is no way to do that, but you can add an additional wrapper with a negative margin:

```css
#inner-wrapper {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
.child {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#inner-wrapper {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
.child {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 210px;
  width: 16.5%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```